# Зеркаливароние ответов от проксируемого сервера

Tags: nginx, proxy

Приветствую.
Есть некий девайс, который отправляет данные на сервер с nginx проксирующим  другой сервер и локальным веб сервисом на 9000 порту.
Вопрос - как отзеркалировать ответ от проксируемого сервера, так что бы он был передан и на девайс, и на локальный веб сервис с 9000 портом? :[image: Схемка]

Answer (score 1):

Используй (*незадокоментированный*) [post_action](http://abarmotik.livejournal.com/7496.html)

Comment: C proxy_pass на мой service:9000 в post_action точно так же проксируются как и на сервер с данными. Мне это не надо.
Мне нужно получить ответ в мой service:9000 только ответ от проксируего сервиса